# How do I Convert an ORACLE SQL Date field to ZULU time with a provided timezone field in the database?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion, timezone

I am trying to convert a date field to zulu time.  The data is pretty simple, a tracking number, a time(which is a date), a timezone, and a zip code.  Is there a way that I can get the time back as zulu time?  So far everything that I have tried has been fruitless. I have tried several permutations of the following:

```
SELECT ORDERNUMBER, to_char(ORDER_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS" "') as orderdatetime, CUST_TIMEZONE, TO_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(to_char(ORDER_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD" "HH24:MI:SS" "'), CUST_TIMEZONE)) FROM MASTER_ORDERS
```

The time field ORDER_DTTM looks like this "6/28/2019 12:00:00 PM" and the Timezone field looks like this "CENTRAL"

Comment: Show what you have tried fruitlessly. What is the data type of the time/date column and the time zone. Please provide some example data.

Comment: So far I just can't get the time offset correctly.  Right now I am running this one:
SELECT ORDERNUMBER, to_char(ORDER_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS" "') as orderdatetime, CUST_TIMEZONE, TO_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(to_char(ORDER_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD" "HH24:MI:SS" "'), CUST_TIMEZONE))
FROM MASTER_ORDERS

The time field ORDER_DTTM looks like this "6/28/2019 12:00:00 PM" and the Timezone field looks like this "CENTRAL"

Comment: Edit your question with new information instead of putting them into a comment.

Comment: What is the data type of `ORDER_DTTM`?

Comment: A time zone named `CENTRAL` does not exist, see [Time Zone Region Names](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/applocaledata.htm#GUID-21D14370-A707-4482-A3FE-9277263F292A)

Comment: ORDER_DTTM is a date.

Comment: Yes, CENTRAL does not exist but this command:
SELECT TZ_OFFSET('US/EASTERN') FROM DUAL;
Will return a proper offset

Answer (score 0):

First you have to attach the time zone to your date value. Then you can convert it to UTC (which is the same as "zulu"). There is a world outside the US, you can concatenate with constant string. If possible, I would recommend to migrate `CUST_TIMEZONE` values to valid time zone names as provided in `SELECT TZNAME FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`

In principle you have to run this:

```
FROM_TZ(ORDER_DTTM, 'US/'||CUST_TIMEZONE) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

However, `FROM_TZ` expects a `TIMESTAMP` value rather than `DATE` and Oracle does not perform an implicit cast, so you have to run

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(ORDER_DTTM AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/'||CUST_TIMEZONE) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

The result is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value. If you like to get back a `DATE` then you have to cast the result again:

```
CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(ORDER_DTTM AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/'||CUST_TIMEZONE) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE)
```

If you convert the timestamp into UTC, you can use also the build-in function, it returns a `TIMESTAMP` value:

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(ORDER_DTTM AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/'||CUST_TIMEZONE))
```